# Android: switch like settings menu

Tags: android, switch-statement, settings, styling

I need to implement the switch widget like the one in the setting menu (like the image below):

[image: switch_android]
The default one is too big, and not like that one.

How can I achieve this? I know how to use images to stylize it, but I don't have the right images neither I know the correct height and width.

Comment: What is the question.. how to get this particular layout? Or how to make a toggle button in your Android view (using the theme and settings of the device it is being run on)?

Comment: to make that particular layout in xml and images

Comment: Hmm you do realize that this will break your users' expectations of how a toggle switch should work right, if it looks different from all the other ones on their system

Comment: because the designer's graphics is like this, and the customer want this. you want to help me or you want to discuss on things that doesn't depends on you?